# Short Error Screen when entering Camera Screen

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, nosuchmethoderror

I am relatively new to dart and created an app, that uses the camera. The whole App works fine, my only problem is that every time I enter the camera screen, I get an error message for a fraction of a second.[Error_Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsGsS.png) Then everything functions as normal. The previous screen is just a home screen, that dosen't pass anything to the camera screen.

Here is the code for the camera screen

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:picer/customButtons.dart';

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  List<CameraDescription> _availableCameras;
  List<String> imageList = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getAvailableCameras();
  }

  // get available cameras
  Future<void> _getAvailableCameras() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _availableCameras = await availableCameras();
    _initCamera(_availableCameras.first);
  }

  // init camera
  Future<void> _initCamera(CameraDescription description) async {
    _controller =
        CameraController(description, ResolutionPreset.max, enableAudio: true);

    await _controller.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: size.width / size.width,
                child: CameraPreview(_controller),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: FileButton(imageList, imageList.length)),
                Expanded(
                  child: CustomShutterButton(
                    controller: _controller,
                    imageList: imageList,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: RawMaterialButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                    width: 70,
                    height: 70,
                  ),
                  fillColor: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _toggleCameraLens();
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.switch_camera,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleCameraLens() {
    // get current lens direction (front / rear)
    final lensDirection = _controller.description.lensDirection;
    CameraDescription newDescription;
    if (lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front) {
      newDescription = _availableCameras.firstWhere((description) =>
          description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back);
    } else {
      newDescription = _availableCameras.firstWhere((description) =>
          description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
    }

    if (newDescription != null) {
      _initCamera(newDescription);
    } else {
      print('Asked camera not available');
    }
  }
}
```

When I build it on my iPhone I get the following Error messages:

```
2020-09-02 15:18:48.470182-0400 Runner[3907:853052] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-09-02 15:18:48.618830-0400 Runner[3907:853246] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:52998/_vfDFTNQegY=/
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157075-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157194-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CameraScreen(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery],
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157220-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: state: _CameraScreenState#0ffaa):
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157242-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: The getter 'value' was called on null.
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157264-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: Receiver: null
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157286-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: Tried calling: value
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157306-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter:
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157327-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: Widget creation tracking is currently disabled. Enabling it enables improved error messages. It can
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157607-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: be enabled by passing `--track-widget-creation` to `flutter run` or `flutter test`.
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157754-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter:
2020-09-02 15:18:51.157949-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158073-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158204-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #1      _CameraScreenState.build (package:picer/cameraScreen.dart:42:23)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158403-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158583-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158718-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158834-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158861-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158914-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:11)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158937-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.158989-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: ...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159012-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159068-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #33     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5991:32)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159091-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: ...     Normal element mounting (136 frames)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159115-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #169    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159174-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #170    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159196-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #171    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5624:32)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159221-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #172    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6001:17)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159272-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #173    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159295-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #174    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159315-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #175    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159334-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #176    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159386-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #177    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4751:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159408-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #178    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159427-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #179    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159447-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #180    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159504-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #181    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4906:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159527-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #182    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:183:11)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159546-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #183    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159566-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #184    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5881:14)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159617-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #185    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159641-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #186    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159664-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #187    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159686-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #188    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159707-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #189    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4751:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159759-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #190    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159780-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #191    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5881:14)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159800-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #192    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159819-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #193    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5881:14)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159840-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #194    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159893-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #195    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159916-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #196    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159935-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #197    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.159955-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #198    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160006-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #199    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160029-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #200    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160050-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #201    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4906:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160071-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #202    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3245:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160094-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #203    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160145-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #204    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160171-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #205    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160194-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #206    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:33)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160223-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #207    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:866:20)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160274-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #208    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160301-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #209    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160322-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #210    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1056:9)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160345-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #211    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:972:5)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160397-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #215    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:253:10)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160425-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: #216    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:211:3)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160446-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160467-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter:
2020-09-02 15:18:51.160501-0400 Runner[3907:853235] flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this issue? I would really appreciate it :) Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved by just checking if the controller is initialized before build.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_controller == null || !_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
```